# C# .NET Web API - Define multiple query parameters struct or class

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm currently working with the web api in .NET Core 3.1 and I'm working with many GET requests that works with pagination (the client sends a request to get items, provides the page number, amount per items, etc, then receives the items).

I noticed that when I want to use this pagination option, it's creating sort of code duplication (every time I need to put this specific code: `[FromQuery] page, [FromQuery] perPage`).
I was wondering if there is a way to define those parameter in one specific option and then use it wherever I need.
That way I will prevent code duplication and it will be much easier if I'll ever make changes to the pagination system.

EDIT: the `page` and `perPage` parameters are `int`s.

Comment: What is the Type of `page` and `perPage` variables?

Comment: My bad, forgot to mention those types - Simple `int` parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class with all property needs for pagination

```
public class QueryParam
{
   public int Page {get; set;}
   public int PerPage {get; set;}
}
```

Then use that class in controller's methods

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomething([FromQuery] QueryParam query)
{
   return Ok();
}
```

Comment: Seems to work great.

I've tried to do the same with struct before opening the question and it just threw an exception but with class it's working, thanks!